# Counting Calls by Half-Hour intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to get the count of calls per half-hour interval.
Couldn't figure it out.

```
select 
       count(call_id) as '#Calls',
       1/2 h(date_time) as 'Call_Interval'
from My_Table
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method to aggregate by various time intervals is with `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(*) as '#Calls',
       DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, '', date_time) / 30) * 30, '') as Call_Interval
FROM dbo.My_Table
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, '', date_time) / 30) * 30, '')
ORDER BY Call_Interval;
```

On a side note, the empty string constant above represents the default value for `datetime`. The default values for `datetime` and other temporal types are listed below, expressed in ISO 8601 string format:

| Data Type | Default Value |
| --- | --- |
| [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql) | 1900-01-01 |
| [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) | 1900-01-01T00:00:00 |
| [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) | 1900-01-01T00:00:00 |
| [datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) | 1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 |
| [smalldatetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql) | 1900-01-01T00:00:00 |
| [time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) | 00:00:00 |

Time interval calculations with a datepart more granular than `minute` (i.e. `second`, `millisecond`, and `microsecond`) may require a more recent base datetime value than the default value (e.g. `2020-01-01T00:00:00`) to avoid overflow.